# Prestashop 1.6 - Get Order ID in new function (Custom Module)

Tags: hook, prestashop-1.6

I have created a custom module and would like to add a new function to execute.

```
public function refund() {
  //retrieve order id
}
```

As opposed to the codes below used in available hooks, how do I retrieve the order id for a new function (not Prestashop available hooks)?

```
public function hookActionProductCancel($params)
{
    $order    = $params['order'];
    $id_order = (int) $order->id;
}
```

It is currently returning 0 as it is not retrieving correctly.

Answer (score 0):

try with this :

```
id_order = $params['id_order'];
```

Regards

Comment: hmmm... its a new function, what is the $params argument then? It does not work, no issues for existing hookDisplayAdminOrder($params) etc

Comment: Truy with $order->id_order, example of Hook :Hook::exec('actionProductCancel', array('order' => $order, 'id_order_detail' => (int)$id_order_detail), null, false, true, false, $order->id_shop);

Comment: It is still not retrieving. I am not using a hook but creating a new function though.